# Get array field from collection using java driver for mongodb

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, collections

I am having problem while trying to extract specific MongoDB fields as an array. So I have a collection named 'users' and nested data in users in a field called 'items' like this:

```
{ "_id" : "1", "username" : "apacheuser", "password" : "Summer95!", "firm" : "apache", "roles" : [ "client,admin" ], "items" : [ { "_id" : "12323", "item-id" : "12312", "item-name" : "İtemic", "price" : 123123, "quantity" : 1231231 }, { "_id" : "123123", "item-id" : "12313", "item-name" : "aftereror", "price" : 1232, "quantity" : 12313213 } ] }
{ "_id" : "2", "username" : "springuser", "password" : "Spring99!", "firm" : "SpringSource", "roles" : [ "client" ], "items" : [ { "_id" : "01231q", "item-id" : "1233", "item-name" : "Patates", "price" : 12321, "quantity" : 12 } ] }
{ "_id" : "3", "username" : "user3", "password" : "Autumn03!", "firm" : "RedHat", "roles" : [ "client" ] }
```

Using the below query, I am able to get the fields that I want, however, for JSON parsing I need to remove the `items` tag from my query result.

```
Bson bsonFilter = Filters.eq("username", "apacheuser");
List<Document> results =db.getCollection("users").find(bsonFilter).projection(fields(include("items"),excludeId()))
```

The expected result is this:

```
[ { "_id" : "12323", "item-id" : "12312", "item-name" : "İtemic", "price" : 123123, "quantity" : 1231231 }, { "_id" : "123123", "item-id" : "12313", "item-name" : "aftereror", "price" : 1232, "quantity" : 12313213 } ] }
```

Instead, I get this:

```
"items" : [{ "_id" : "12323", "item-id" : "12312", "item-name" : "İtemic", "price" : 123123.0, "quantity" : 1231231 }, { "_id" : "123123", "item-id" : "12313", "item-name" : "aftereror", "price" : 1232.0, "quantity" : 12313213 }] }
```

So it's quite obvious that I just need to remove the `'items'` tag to parse correctly. But I am confused about how to do that.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting? A number of documents as opposed to an array with a number of subdocuments in it? Or just a JSON array with no field name? The latter would not be valid JSON so that is certainly impossible.

Comment: unwind "items"?

Comment: @dnickless i am trying to  get A number of Documents with subdocuments in it as I mentioned in expected result field so I tried 'unwind' method. Unfortunately, its still giving me wrong data. I also tried to $group items based on matched 'username' field, however this gives me extra 'username' field which must be extracted from result query.

Comment: any solution ? @dnickless

Comment: Frankly, I haven't understood yet what you need. You're saying you want documents with subdocuments but I don't see any subdocuments in your expected result. Can you perhaps make it clearer what the individual documents should look like? What you need is probably either `$unwind` or `$replaceRoot` or something but I cannot really tell like this.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, that was my fault to say subdocument so it should be array of documents. I have a collection named users and inside it I have usernames and each username contains array of documents like "items":[_id,item-id .....]. So what I want is just get items without "items" tag and store them in ArrayList. Actually, until now I have tried many queries like $unwind,$elemMatch,$group, and projection but I always get items array with "items" tag so with this result I am unable to parse as JSON. I need to just get rid of "items" tag. I hope its clearer now. @dnickless

Comment: This is probably what you want: `db.users.aggregate({
    $unwind: "$items"
}, {
    $replaceRoot: { "newRoot": "$items" }
})`

Comment: @dnickless thanks for help, it worked as I wish. Here is the solution with java driver:  BasicDBObject match=new BasicDBObject("$match",new BasicDBObject("username",apacheuser));
         BasicDBObject unwind= new BasicDBObject("$unwind","$items");
         BasicDBObject trans= new BasicDBObject("$replaceRoot",new BasicDBObject("newRoot","$items"));
     ArrayList<BasicDBObject> pipeline = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();         pipeline.add(match);pipeline.add(unwind);pipeline.add(trans);List<Document> results =db.getCollection("users").aggregate(pipeline).into(new ArrayList<Document>());